# Is there an ESLint rule to prevent truthy checks

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I want to avoid accidentally invoking Javascript's insane [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) system. Are there any ESLint rules to help with this? Especially in `if` statements. For example:

```
const a: number = 0;
const b: string | null = null;
if (a) { ... } // Should be an error.
if (b) { ... } // Should be an error.
if (a !== 0) { ... } // Ok
if (b !== null) { ... } // Ok
```

I thought `no-implicit-coercion` might do the job but it seems like it doesn't cover this case.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if there is a rule that will do that, but if there is it will need to be a typescript-eslint rule. Javascript alone doesn't have enough information to statically determine if coercion will happen. You can see the typescript-eslint rules here: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin/src/rules

Comment: Aha, found it, thanks! [strict-boolean-expressions](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/strict-boolean-expressions.md)